# Test SP Designer 2013 with SP Server 2013 without license?

Tags: 2013

I am to develop SP application in SP Server 2013. I downloaded the trial version of SP Server 2013 and SP Designer 2013 to make some test application, unfortunately, I can't use SP Designer with the SP Server since it's a trial version. Now, my questions:

1) How can I test SP Designer with SP Server without license? Is that possible?

2) If my only choice is SP Foundation for testing, can I migrate my application from SP Foundation to SP Server?

Answer (score 2):

1) As far as I known there should be no problems using SP Designer with the trial version of SP Server

2) Migrating SharePoint Designer "applications" from SP Foundation to SP Server is as easy (or really as hard) as migrating them from SP Server. SP Designer isn't really designed for a Dev => Test => Staging => Prod application lifecycle.